# Searching for a gnome app/shell extension to convert units

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I am looking for an app or perhaps a shell extension that can convert all kinds of units to each other. It should preferably work in the search overview (that thing that comes up when you press SUPER), similar how the calculator app does.
Calculator app: when you put in 40 * 20 it spits out 800 and copies it to the clipboard if you hit enter.
The Extension/App: when you put in 40F to C, or simpler 40F C it spits out what 40°F is in Celsius. It doesn't need currencies, but it would of course be nice.
Other examples include
4inch cm
6foot m
5lb kg

or something like that.
Does anybody know of an app or a shell extension for this functionality?

(also I'm unsure if this is the right forum to post this to, please redirect me to a better place if it isn't)

Thanks in advance!

Also it needs to work in gnome 43, so this https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/122/unit-converter/ is out of the question, it seems great tho!